# How geo tagging helps in storing location data in DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, dynamo-local

I want to save the following historical location data in DynamoDB:

- deviceid
- timestamp
- latitude
- longitude

The database should cater for the listing of location for a device id between two timestamps.

Will geo tagging help?

I have defined the Location table in the following way:

```js
from __future__ import print_function # Python 2/3 compatibility
import boto3

dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb', region_name='us-west-2', endpoint_url="http://localhost:8000")


table = dynamodb.create_table(
    TableName='LocationOne',
    KeySchema=[
        {
            'AttributeName': 'deviceid',
            'KeyType': 'HASH'  #Partition key
        },
        {
            'AttributeName': 'timestamp',
            'KeyType': 'RANGE'  #Sort key
        }
       
    ],
    AttributeDefinitions=[
        {
            'AttributeName': 'deviceid',
            'AttributeType': 'S'
        },
        {
            'AttributeName': 'timestamp',
            'AttributeType': 'N'
        }

    ],
    ProvisionedThroughput={
        'ReadCapacityUnits': 10,
        'WriteCapacityUnits': 10
    }
)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "Will geo tagging help"? Help with what? Could you please clarify your actual question? Are you using a library like [Geo Library for Amazon DynamoDB](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/geo-library-for-amazon-dynamodb-part-1-table-structure/)?

Comment: I am not using the library, I want to know in what way using this Geo Library help.